# Как отобразить в QtTextBrowser данные из БД Sqlite в Python

Tags: python, qt, sqlite

Проблема собственно в следующем. Есть вот такая функция, которая должна выводить в QtTextBrowser все значения из БД Sqlite:

```
def value(self):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("data.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table;")

    for row in cursor:
        self.textBrowser.setText(str(row))

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Однако в самом приложении в TextBrowser выводится только последняя строка из всей таблицы, пробовал разными способами и с помощью `.fetchall()` и `.fetchone()`, в общем не могу сообразить.

Как мне сделать, чтобы выводились абсолютно все значения?

Answer (score 0):

> QTextEdit::setText(const QString &text)
>
> Устанавливает текст редактирования текста. 
>   Текст может быть простым текстом или HTML, и текстовое редактирование будет пытаться угадать правильный формат.
>   Используйте setHtml() или setPlainText() напрямую, чтобы избежать угадывания редактирования текста.
>
> **Внимание !!! Любой предыдущий текст удаляется.**

---

> QTextEdit::**append**(const QString &text)
>
> **Добавляет новый абзац с текстом в конец редактирования текста**.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Demo(QWidget):    
    def __init__(self):        
        super().__init__()

        self.textBrowser = QTextBrowser()

        self.button = QPushButton("Show")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.showDb)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.textBrowser)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def showDb(self):
        for row in range(12):
#            self.textBrowser.setText(str(row))
            self.textBrowser.append(str(row))                     # <<<-----<


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w  = Demo()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]